# Laptop only recognizes (Intel SSD 660p Series) NVMe disk when external monitors are disconnected

Tags: laptop, ssd, power, external-display, nvme

I'm facing this most strange issue with my laptop.

My laptop has 3 video ports:

- 2 mini display port
- 1 hdmi port

On which I connect 3 external monitors.

[image: Screenshot of my 3 video ports]

When I turn on the computer, it boots straight into BIOS, because the NVMe disk is listed as “Empty.” Every day for the past year I had to disconnect the cables on the video ports, boot the computer, and plug them back in to be able to use my laptop.

I've got in touch with the manufacturer, they said I'm using a NVMe disk that they don't have "homologation" for, which sounds kinda like nonsense to me, since a laptop with NVMe should be able to run any NVMe disks.

I use an Intel SSD 660p Series (2.0TB). They said they have homologation for Rocket and Samsung EVO.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

I thought this could be related to power draw, so I have tried with a higher PSU, a Chicony 230W, the original is 180W, got the same results. Disconnecting USB devices does not seem to have any effect on this issue.

Comment: Have you tried reseating the NVMe card in the system? Sometimes something as simple as that can clear things up.

Comment: Are you able to try with different mDP cables (good ones)? It seems that mDP/DP cables that are not properly wired could cause boot failure, among other issues.

Comment: Is your PSU strong enough to support booting with everything connected? Boot is power-demanding.